# Python Function for Altering shapefile's attribute datatype

Tags: arcpy

I want to merge a few hundred shapefiles depending on geometry type, which are in several directories and subdirectories. i have written a python script and i am using mainly arcpy for the routines. But the process cannot be completed as there is a problem on the datatype of a common attribute in all shapefiles. In most of shapefiles the datatype of this attribute is **string** and in some other is **double**. I found the shapefiles with attribute datatype double, but these are a few, and cannot be done one by one. So i am looking for a function that changes the datatype of this attribute, filtering the current datatype.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe it is not possible to change the datatype of an existing field.  An alternative would be to, using arcpy if you are comfortable, add a new field with the desired datatype, copy values from the old to new, and delete the old.

Comment: Building on @Barbarossa's comments, you can use Featureclass to Featureclass to copy the new FC's and use field mappings to add, rename, or delete output fields as well as set properties such as data type and merge rule. http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000020000000

Comment: You might consider creating a blank featureclass (with appropriate datatypes) and using Append to merge the featureclasses. Append has no problem merging a numeric field and a text field into a destination text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Barbarossa said, you cannot change the type of a field, and you cannot merge fields of different types.

so, for doing it automatically in Python, you need to create a new field, copy the value and delete the old field (the last step is not necessary

```
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in fcs:
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "new_field", "TEXT")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "new_field", """ str(!old_field!) """)
    arcpy.DeleteField_management(fc, "old_field)
```

note that you could use string formating for your string conversion """ {}.format(!old_field!) """ if yo want more control.